# Switch Compat remove right padding

Tags: android

I have a `<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` and currently the toggle has some padding to the right side. I want to remove this so that the toggle is directly touching the edge. I have tried setting 
`<item name="android:paddingRight">`
and

`<item name="android:paddingEnd">` to 0dp but there is still a padding present.

Comment: have you tried negative dp :) -10dp for example :)